# angular.js example not working in codepen and in local environment

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, codepen

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#red">Red</a>
<a href="#green">Green</a>
<a href="#blue">Blue</a>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
});
</script>

<p>Click on the links to navigate to "red.htm", "green.htm", "blue.htm", or back to "main.htm"</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This above snippet is copied from http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing, its working there but when copied and pasted in codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYMrwy its not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: do you have the templates as well? (main.html, etc...)

Comment: no I dont have the templates

Comment: I added blue.htm still its not working ...

Comment: Angular.js routing is having a problem

Comment: see the answer below. It is not routing. it is the template compiler that was throwing you a console error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... try this code instead. I've replaced all the missing templates with inline templates. You are simply missing the files.

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#red">Red</a>
<a href="#green">Green</a>
<a href="#blue">Blue</a>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        template : "main"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        template : "red"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        template : "green"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        template : "blue"
    });
});
</script>

<p>Click on the links to navigate to "red.htm", "green.htm", "blue.htm", or back to "main.htm"</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I want to use templateUrl.

Comment: then have all the html files in place. you need main.html, red.html, blue.html and green.html to be found. This snipset just shows that your routing is fine.

Comment: Well.. here is a plunker example for you with templates. It is working. https://plnkr.co/edit/r8Mmem0w3WCof3R9Pikk?p=preview Youäve got to use developers consol to see, what is missing.